# BATCH vs MANUAL and ack vs commit

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

In the documentation :

> BATCH: Commit the offset when all the records returned by the poll()
> have been processed.
>
> MANUAL: The message listener is responsible to acknowledge() the
> Acknowledgment. After that, the same semantics as BATCH are applied.

if the offset is committed when all the records returned by the poll() have been processed for both cases then I don't get the difference, can you give me a scenario when MANUAL ack mode is used differently ?

If I use MANUAL mode and I don't call `acknowledge()` within my KafkaListener would be the same as BATCH mode ? and if I call `acknowledge()` what would change ?

Maybe I don't get the difference between commit and acknowledge notions within spring kafka

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the perfect world, when your application is always UP, you definitely don't need those commits at all. Just because Kafka Consumer keeps the track of offset internally between poll calls. There might be the case when you really don't need to commit on every single batch delivered to you. That's when that `MANUAL` comes to the rescue. With `BATCH` mode you don't have control and the framework perform it for you anyway. With `MANUAL` you may decide to commit now or later on, some where after a couple batches processed.

It is called `acknowledge` because we might not perform a commit immediately, but rather store it in-memory for subsequent poll cycle. The commit must be performed exactly on the Kafka consumer thread.

Comment: `some where after a couple batches processed` do you mean that inside my KafkaListener i can do some condition logic for acknowledging and that might happens in other polls ? and with MANUAL the last offsets that have been acknowledged will be committed in the next poll ?

Comment: so with MANUAL the committed offset that will be sent with poll is not necessary equal to the last processed record in a batch but to the last one acknowledged ?

Comment: As long as your listener is single-threaded it is fully safe to skip acks for some reason. Whenever you decide to ack, only the higher offset is committed. See `MANUAL_IMMEDIATE` for different behavior. Actually all of that is explained in the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#committing-offsets

Comment: That's not correct: if there are acks to commit, we commit first then call consumer poll. So, it is not possible to get fresh records in the listener before scheduled commit is performed. The `Acknowledgment.acknowledge()` does track the current offset for records given to your listener.

Comment: so in my statement I was wrong just about the order of the commit operation, the call to commitSync() or commitAsync() is done before poll, and the reset is correct, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, I think now we are on the same page. Feel free to raise a GH issue if something is not clear in the docs, so we will revise to our best.